# Haven't been working for the company for 1.5 weeks: give notice or end immediately?

Tags: professionalism, notice-period

Follow-up question to [Lack of hours at work: address to the manager or not, and explaining in a job application](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40100/lack-of-hours-at-work-address-to-the-manager-or-not-and-explaining-in-a-job-ap).

My girlfriend has not had *any* hours with the company mentioned in the question above for 1.5 weeks now and just got a job offer. Furthermore, **no communication has occurred between my girlfriend and her manager** in that amount of time. My girlfriend will be starting this new job in a week (note: not two weeks) and will contact her manager tomorrow. I have two questions about how she should address her manager:

- Would it be appropriate to address the manager by phone if my girlfriend hasn't been at work for 1.5 weeks?
- Would it be appropriate to quit immediately without the one-week notice (i.e., without a one-week break before her next job)?

Comment: In the linked question, there was no written contract between your girlfriend and her manager. Your girlfriend can do whatever she likes, so can her manager.

Comment: Is this a Zero Hours contract/job ?

Comment: @Pepone - If you look at the linked post, my gf was told that she would be getting ~12 hours/week.

Comment: @Clarinetist yes I saw that but what type of contract was she on did it guarantee 12 hours work a week

Comment: @Pepone - In the original post, there were no papers she signed, so I guess you could say there wasn't a contract other than what her employer promised verbally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let's see if I understand this correctly: Your girlfriend is officially employed. However, she doesn't get a monthly or weekly pay, but is paid per hour that she works, and in the last 1.5 weeks she hasn't been given any work, therefore hasn't received any income.

She could obviously give two weeks notice, but also notify the company that during the notice period she will not work more hours than in the week before the notice was given. Which would be zero hours.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from your other post as background, to make sure that everybody is on the same page: "My girlfriend works for a small business which sells items. She started there two months ago and did not sign any papers. When she applied, she was told that she would be getting a 12-hour work week. However, her manager (the owner of the business) seems to randomly drop her hours in times in which there seems to be no demand (e.g., when there is bad weather, and no one probably will come by to buy anything). This has gotten to the point where the amount of hours my girlfriend worked in the last three weeks were 8, 6, and 3 hours respectively"

Given that her manager has been jerking her around ever since she started working for him, she doesn't owe him anything and that includes her notice. He hasn't done anything to deserve her respect and in my book, he should get none. If I were her, I'd start on the new job and I'd let him figure out that I am not available the next time he calls - I am not picking up the phone and he can talk to my answering machine for all I care. Those who treat me fairly get the two-week notice. Those who don't get what I feel like giving them - usually, nothing.

Once upon a time, I gave my two-week notice to a boss whom I knew to be unethical. While his underling promised to give me my accrued vacation - small reward for the 60-hour weeks I put in - his boss proceeded to cheat me of both the accrued vacation and my last two-week's pay. Not particularly funny considering that I had two dependents. My attitude is that her manager did not keep his word regarding her hours. He caused her financial hardship, disrupted her schedule and caused an awkward moment for her whenever she had to mention her reason for leaving at an interview, so screw him.

Comment: -1: In most jurisdictions and work contracts, the notice period is a legal obligation which must be fulfilled no matter how much you hate your boss.

Comment: @Philipp: in the US almost all employees are at-will, meaning they can leave or be dismissed without notice.

Comment: @Phikioo Back up your claim. "From the OP's other post: "My girlfriend works for a small business which sells items. She started there two months ago and did not sign any papers. When she applied, she was told that she would be getting a 12-hour work week. However, her manager (the owner of the business) seems to randomly drop her hours in times in which there seems to be no demand (e.g., when there is bad weather, and no one probably will come by to buy anything). This has gotten to the point where the amount of hours my girlfriend worked in the last three weeks were 8, 6, and 3 hours"

Comment: @Philipp http://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/can-an-at-will-employer-require-employees-to-give--1388905.html "Answer is no - no requirement by law to give two weeks' notice in New York State." So New York State is one place where you are making up your own set of facts. Again, she never signed any contract.

Comment: @Philipp http://www.employees-lawyer.com/two-weeks-notice-requirements-california/ Answer is no - no requirement by law to give two weeks' notice in California. Again, you are making up your own set of facts. She never signed any contract.

Comment: @Philipp http://www.ncsl.org/research/labor-and-employment/at-will-employment-overview.aspx "Employment relationships are presumed to be “at-will” in all U.S. states except Montana" "At-will means that an employer can terminate an employee at any time for any reason, except an illegal one, or for no reason without incurring legal liability.  Likewise, an employee is free to leave a job at any time for any or no reason with no adverse legal consequences." So again, BACK UP YOUR CLAIM that despite the fact that she never signed a contract, she is still legally obligated to give two week's notice

Comment: -1: Racial slurs don't have a place here.

Comment: +1:  Oh, this answer's fine.  At least where I live, two weeks notice is a professional *courtesy*,  given to those who deserve it (or at least to those who haven't demonstrated that they don't deserve it).

Comment: @Myles What racial slurs? You are making up your own set of facts, too?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan "...proceeded to gyp me of..." Gyp used in this context is a slur against the Romany.  It paints Romany (or gypsies) as theives and cheats.  It is on par with saying "...proceeded to jew me of..." which I'm sure we can agree is not ok.

Comment: @Myles I don't have anything against gypsies - I just looked up "gyp": there are allegations that "gyp" is derived from "gypsies" but no proof. However, in view of the baggage, I'll use some other term. Like cheating.`

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan How do you know the laws of some US states are applicable here? The OP doesn't even say what country they are from. They could be *anywhere* in the world. Also, a work contract could make a notice mandatory. Again, not *everywhere* in the world. Remember that there are 7 billion people in the world, and only 316 millions of them live and work in the US.

Comment: @Philipp You can't back up your claim. Your statements clearly have no applicability in the United States. Your speciousness and ignorance are obvious. If the OP is not n the US, let the OP say so.